# Package Loading: "Ignoring duplicate product" (SwiftPM)

Tags: swift, warnings, compiler-warnings, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to build a Swift package using the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/).

However, when I open the package in Xcode and click **Run**, I get the following warning:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an issue often encountered if you are attempting to build a library/framework but also have a `main.swift` file in your target's root directory, like so:

[image].

The presence of a `main.swift` file makes SwiftPM believe that you are attempting to build a command line tool, and thus complains about the unnecessary (duplicate in name) library produced.

This warning may be confusing as it does not occur in projects initialized with the dynamic framework template from Xcode, for iOS, macOS, tvOS or watchOS.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because I had the same name in both the `products` section and the `Package` e.g.

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "Example",
    products: [
        .library(
             name: "Example",
             targets: ["Example"]),
    ],
)
```

This seems to be the default behavior of `swift init` for some reason.  I removed the `.library` entry and the warning went away.